# Haskell convert Word8 to Int to Bits

Tags: haskell, bit

I want to convert a Word8 to an Int so I can convert it to a list of Bits is there anyway to convert it to either an int or straight to bits?

This is my current snippet of a code

```
intsToBits :: Int -> [Bit]
intsToBits x  =
  reverse (go x) where
  go 0 = [Zero]
  go n | n `mod` 2 == 1 = One : go (n `div` 2)
       | n `mod` 2 == 0 = Zero : go (n `div` 2)
  go _ = []

word8ToInt :: Word8 -> Int
word8ToInt = fromIntegral

decoder :: BS.ByteString -> IO [Bit]
decoder raw =
  do
     let raw' = BS.unpack raw
     let ls = go raw'
     return ls
       where
         go []     = []
         go [x]    = intsToBits $  x
         go (x:xs) = intsToBits (word8ToInt x) ++ go xs
```

Comment: Why are you in the IO monad in the decoder function? You aren't even using it. You could just write `decoder = go . BS.unpack where go = [...]`

Comment: You have given your `intsToBits` function the type `Int -> [Bit]`. But this is not the most general type of this function! The most general type is `Integral a => a -> [Bit]`. In other words, you've already got the function you need, just change the type. With this type,`intsToBits` will happily accept a `Word8`. Then you simply have `decoder = concatMap intsToBits . unpack`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta on asking questions: You really should give some examples of how you tried to solve the problem.  Shy of that, at least an example of the result you want such as what "bits" means to you.   I tend to think of a collection of `Word8` values as bits and so there is operation to be performed.

That said, lets pose and answer a series of related questions.

**What are the bit operators in Haskell?**

If you want bit level operations, instead of doing arithmetic tricks like `x || 2^i` you can use the functions from the Bits class:

```
Prelude> import Data.Bits
Prelude Data.Bits> :i Bits
class Eq a => Bits a where
  (.&.) :: a -> a -> a
  (.|.) :: a -> a -> a
  xor :: a -> a -> a
  complement :: a -> a
  shift :: a -> Int -> a
  rotate :: a -> Int -> a
  zeroBits :: a
  bit :: Int -> a
  setBit :: a -> Int -> a
  clearBit :: a -> Int -> a
  complementBit :: a -> Int -> a
  testBit :: a -> Int -> Bool
  bitSizeMaybe :: a -> Maybe Int
  bitSize :: a -> Int
  isSigned :: a -> Bool
  shiftL :: a -> Int -> a
  unsafeShiftL :: a -> Int -> a
  shiftR :: a -> Int -> a
  unsafeShiftR :: a -> Int -> a
  rotateL :: a -> Int -> a
  rotateR :: a -> Int -> a
  popCount :: a -> Int
```

And also the `FiniteBits` class:

```
class Bits b => FiniteBits b where
  finiteBitSize      :: b -> Int
  countLeadingZeros  :: b -> Int
  countTrailingZeros :: b -> Int
```

**How can I convert `Word8` to `[Bool]`?**

This is simply testing each bit in the word, and b

```
toBits x = [testBit x i | i <- [0.. finiteBitSize x - 1]
```

**How can I convert `Word8` to some datatype I called `Bit` that I won't show you?**

After your first edit I now think you have `data Bit = Zero | One` but am unclear if that's correct.  It seems like homework and the advice given here should suffice to get the rest of the way either way.

Comment: It is `data Bit = Zero | One`. It's not HW, it's a project

Answer (score 3):

`Word8` is an instance of the `FiniteBits` class, so you can use something like

```
toBitList x = map (testBit x) [0..(finiteBitSize x-1)]
```

Or if you want it the other way around, `[(finiteBitSize x-1), (finiteBitSize x-2)..0]`.

---

I see from your edit that you (apparently) want your bits in order from most significant to least significant, and you don't want any leading zeros. There are various ways to do this, but the easiest is probably to modify the above approach using `countLeadingZeros`.

Comment: I need to apply this to my own datatype called `Bit` where each is represented by either `One` or `Zero` so how can I do that here?

Comment: @asyiefel, you're going to have to show your efforts before I can go further.

Comment: I've updated the above with a snippet of the code. I can provide all if necessary